# How to examine a dynamically created bootstrap4 element in Firefox?

Tags: firefox, bootstrap-4, firefox-developer-tools

I have an issue with a bootstrap4 select item.

Code:

```
<select name="sprache" size="1" class="form-control form-control-sm">
  <option value="de" SELECTED>deutsch</option>
  <option value="en">english</option>
</select>
```

When clicking into the select it opens and shows both options.

In Chrome items have same font as select control itself:

[image]

But in Firefox items have a different font:

[image]

And I'm not able to find out why it is like this.
I tried bootstrap custom-select as well with same result.

And I can't find out how to examine the created box to get the classes used.
FF contextmenu is not available and in code inspector the select box is not shown at all.

First question: which classes uses bootstrap for this box?
Second: how to ge classes with ff developer tools?

Thanks for your hints
Fabian

Answer (score 0):

in fact I found no answer for none of the questions.

Now I switched bootstrap select to jquery ui select.
There I was able to do all I wanted and it wotks in all browsers.

Fabian